# Plotly R: Create scatter plot divided into categories

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, categorical-data

I have a set of data arranged by different categories. I would like create a plotly scatter plot that arranges the data points by categories in separate columns. Similar to [this.](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/user-guide/hmfile_hash_4894254f.png)

The X axis should be the categories, but the data within each category should not fall in the same x coordinate, so that the visualization is not compromised.

How should I proceed?

I've tried to look for information in the official plotly website, but the only similar thing I found was [this website](https://plotly-r.com/scatter-traces.html), where the chapter 3.2.4 shows a parallel coordinates plot. Is there a way to modify that so that it looks like the picture above? Does it even make sense to try that?

Comment: Take a look at `geom_jitter` with `plotly`: https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_jitter/ - is this what you have in mind?

Comment: @Ben Yes! This is definitely what I have in mind. I've seen that it's based on ggplot2 but still remains interactive, which is something I didn't want to lose. Thanks!